# any way to track install_referrer for sideloaded android app?

Tags: android

I know apps that dl from play store is able to pass referral data, but is there a way to pass data to sideloaded app? Let's say if I want to promote my app, and I have 10 affiliates. they all want to sideload my app. is it correct that the only way i can track traffic is by doing 10 separate builds? or if there's a way to send data like `install_referrer`?

from my understanding, the only way to trigger `install_referrer` is through google play store. If that's the case, is there an easy way to do builds? in case if I have over hundreds of affiliates later.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I wish to pass data via an INSTALL_REFERRER without Play as well.

Comment: no, i dont think theres an easy way